# One or more errors occurred. (java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.)'

Tags: c#, api, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm working on xamarin, but I'm not very knowledgeable yet. I have a problem, I have an API application that I run locally and that I wrote. When I run it locally, I can exchange data with POSTMAN without any problems.
When I try to connect to my local API connection with Xamarin, I get the following error;

System.AggregateException: 'One or more errors occurred. (java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.)'

Here is my triggered code:

```
public void OnLoginButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();
            var responseMessage = _client.GetAsync("https://10.0.2.2:44375/weatherforecast").Result;
            List<Weather> weathers = null;
            if(responseMessage.StatusCode==System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                weathers = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Weather>>(responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
            }   
        }
```

I get the error when I get to this line;

```
var responseMessage = _client.GetAsync("https://10.0.2.2:44375/weatherforecast").Result;
```

This code did not work for me, unfortunately I am using .NET 4.5 above.

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (o, cert, chain, errors) => true;
```

Any suggestions on how I can solve this problem?

I tried many ways and no result. There must be a very simple reason why I can't communicate with Xamarin when I can communicate with API in a web project or via POSTMAN but I can't find where is this problem.

Comment: there are [dozens](https://www.google.com/search?q=Trust+anchor+for+certification+path+not+found.+site:stackoverflow.com) of posts about this error.  Have you thoroughly read through them and tried the suggestions offered?

Comment: When an application uses a local secure web service, it is necessary to ignore SSL errors. You can try by setting the `ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback` property on a `HttpClientHandler` object to a callback that ignores the result of the certificate security check for the local HTTPS development certificate. Refer to the official document: [Bypass the certificate security check](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/deploy-test/connect-to-local-web-services#bypass-the-certificate-security-check)

Comment: @Jason I've searched many threads but can't find a solution.

Comment: @DongzhiWang-MSFT unfortunately this doesn't work for me

Comment: @Kemal On which platform are you having this problem, iOS or Android? Are you using a self-signed certificate?

Comment: @DongzhiWang-MSFT   I am trying in android environment,

Comment: Did the answer in this thread ([Trust anchor for certification path not found.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/96c08205-0eb4-45ef-b384-de6904722c99/trust-anchor-for-certification-path-not-found?forum=xamarinforms#:~:text=in%20to%20vote-,User380049%20posted,-%40JeffLim%20said%3A%20Cool)) help you?